# How do I calculate image size for print

Tags: images

I've got an image 4,200 x 4,200 pixels. I want to have it printed off as the biggest poster size I can get. How do I calculate what the largest size would be before I get pixelation or fuzziness. It's a very detailed image so it needs to retain the quality. Below is a link if that provides any details I've excluded.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Observable_universe_logarithmic_illustration.png

Comment: This is nearly impossible to answer as it depends on viewing distance and size. If you just want no fuzziness then the general starting point would be 4,200 x 4,200 at 300ppi giving you 14inches x 14inches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some initial observations:

You do not read a magazine at 2 m. from you. Lets think that you read it at 30 cm.

But you can see a poster at 60cm, or a bus stop add at 1 or 2 m.

[image]

As you get further away you need less resoluiton on your print.

So the first point is define your viewing distance.

If what you want is a wall mounted image on your room, I say it is arround 100-150 ppi. For me 100ppi is enough, so lets do some math:

- 4200px/100ppi = 42 inches.
- 4200px/150ppi = 28 inches.

I would recomend that you print a small fragment of the image on a letter sized paper and then you decide the final resolution.